# How to convert a scientific notation string to decimal notation?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to `find` and `convert` all scientific notation strings in a csv file to decimal notation, e.g.:

```
1.0e-05 to 0.00001
```

How can I do that in ruby?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use string conversion. The necessary coercion to float will be done automatically:

```
"%f" % "1.0e-05"
=> "0.000010"

# Which, behind the scenes is the same as:
"%f" % "1.0e-05".to_f
=> "0.000010"
```

Adjust as necessary to get more or less accuracy. For example:

```
"%.5f" % "1.0e-05"
=> "0.00001"
```

If you want to get real fancy and chop off unnecessary zeros at the end, here's one way. (Hopefully someone will suggest something more elegant; I couldn't think of anything):

```
("%.20f" % "1.0e-05").sub(/\.?0*$/, "")
=> "0.00001"
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're interested in doing any sort of math on a number and it is too small:

```
"%f" % "1.0e-10"
=> "0.000000"

# not so good for various reasons
("%f" % "1.0e-10") == ("%f" % "1.0e-8")
=> true
```

You can use BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal.new "1.0e-10"
=> #<BigDecimal:7ffdf6c38678,'0.1E-9',9(18)>
```